Can I be held liable for tax obligations by simply accepting Ordinary Shares without further action?
I've been granted the opportunity to accept a certain number of Ordinary (voting) shares with a nominal value of £0.01 each, along with an exercise option. This option allows me to exercise these shares within the next 10 years at an exercise price of £3.60 per share. However, I am uncertain about the tax implications of accepting these shares.
My understanding is that by accepting these shares, I'm not immediately liable for any taxes. Instead, I have the option to exercise them at the specified price within the given timeframe. If I choose not to exercise them, they would expire worthless. However, I am concerned about potential tax obligations if I do decide to accept them without taking any further action.
Example

Number of shares: 2000 Ordinary (voting) shares with a nominal value of £0.01 each
Exercise up until: 10 years after grant
Exercise price: £3.60 per share

Let's say I accept these shares and choose not to take any further action this year. In the following year, the market price of the shares increases to £15 per share. At this point, I have the option to exercise these shares, which means I should pay £3.60 x 2000 = £7200. The question arises: can I simply wait for the price to rise, then buy at £3.60 and immediately sell at the higher market price, say £15 per share? Is this how it works, or should I exercise the shares first and then wait for the price to fluctuate, accepting the inherent risk involved? Additionally, I would like to know what happens if the price decreases.

These are great questions to ask your lawyer.

It sounds like you are being offered options, not shares.  The tax implications of the two are likely different so you want to be very clear about that.  Your first sentence starts off saying that you're being offered shares but everything else seems to indicate that you are being given stock options.

Why might you be taxed for an option that you never exercise?

@MichaelHall if the option has value at the time you are given it, then receiving it could be the same as receiving compensation.

@Grade'Eh'Bacon, An option not exercised is worth about as much as the printed cash value on an unused paper coupon.

This is why options are a popular form of compensation. They don't cost the company much, and the employee defers taxation until they exercise and later sell the shares.
